# difficulty with deep lists

Tags: prolog

This is my code and it doesnt work.

```
skip([], []).

skip([H|T], [H|R]):-
    atomic(H),
    !,
    skip(T, R).

skip([_|T], R):-
    skip(T, R).


tails([], []).

tails([H|T], R]):-
    atomic(H),
    !,
    skip(T, T1),
    tails(T1, R).

tails([H|T], [H|R]):-
    tails(H, R1),
    skip(T, T1),
    tails(T1, R2),
    append(R1, R2, R).
```

If we input list `L = [1, [2, 3, [4, 5] ] ]` the result should be `R = [1, 3, 5].`

Comment: This is supposed to be a predicate returning the elements from a deep lists, which are at the end of a shallow list (immediately before a ‘]’).

Comment: This cannot be actual running code, because of typo at `tails([H|T],R]):-`

Comment: apart from the mistake pointed out by @CapelliC, your last clause seems dubious. A good starting point would be for you to explain in english what you'd like it to do so that we can match the program behavior with its intended behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure I understood your requirements, but this code satisfies your sample.

```
tails([], []).
tails([E], [E]) :-
    atomic(E), !.
tails([E,[H|T]|Es], [E|Rs]) :-
    atomic(E), !,
    tails([H|T], Qs),
    tails(Es, Ts),
    append(Qs, Ts, Rs).
tails([_|Es], Rs) :-
    tails(Es, Rs).
```

test:

```
?- tails([1,[2,3,[4,5]]],L).
L = [1, 3, 5].
```